# Typescript 1000 errors with visual studio and angular 2

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

I'm not able to run a sample application in visual studio using angular 2

[Link](https://github.com/shruti1006/VisualStudio) to the code

**Error screenshot**

[image]

**Visual studio info**

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038

Installed Version: Enterprise

Architecture and Modeling Tools   00322-80000-00000-AA238
Microsoft Architecture and Modeling Tools

UML® and Unified Modeling Language™ are trademarks or registered trademarks of the Object Management Group, Inc. in the United States and other countries.

Visual Basic 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA238
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA238
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA238
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   5.209.60613.1
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11106.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Common Azure Tools   1.7
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Language Service

JavaScript Project System   2.0
JavaScript Project System

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

NuGet Package Manager   3.4.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60311.1
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript   1.8.31.0
TypeScript tools for Visual Studio

Though i installed the 2.2.2 typescript but its not showing here.

Can anybody help?

Comment: if you installed 2.2.2 and its showing another version, most likely thats your problem, right? If I was you, I would uninstall and reinstall the typescript extension.

Comment: Not like to check your code but it may help [you](https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa) [this](http://www.mithunvp.com/using-angular-2-asp-net-mvc-5-visual-studio/)

Comment: ya but how to solve that.I have restarted the system,restarted visual studio but it still wont reflect.

Comment: I'm using VS Code 1.14.2 - not sure if it's same on your version, but you can see  version of typescript in blue banner at bottom right of screen.. I have a settings.JSON file for VSCode too, found in the preferences /settings on a mac.. That has a lot of Typescript settings...